# how do I calculate TAR (%) @ FAR = 0.1% in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was reading a paper and the results in the paper are presented in the following way:

[image]

I want to have a similar table for my model. Using the below code I got FAR and TAR values.

```
from sklearn import metrics

test = [0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1, 0]        
pred = [0.04172871, 0.01611879, 0.01073375, 0.03344169 ,0.04172871, 0.04172871, 0.00430162 ,0.04172871 ,0.04172871 ,0.04172871 ,0.07977659, 0.905772,0.9396076,  0.03344169, 0.04172871, 0.09125287, 0.02964183, 0.0641269,0.04172871 ,0.04172871, 0.04172871, 0.0641269 , 0.04172871, 0.04172871,0.9919831 , 0.04172871, 0.01611879 ,0.04172871, 0.37865442 ,0.00240888]
far, tar, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(Y_test,p)
```

How should I fix FAR = 0.1% and How do I calculate TAR% @FAR = 0.1% using Python?

Comment: You just need to understand how to interpret the `tar` and `far` arrays. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340737/thresholds-false-positive-rate-true-positive-rate

Comment: I have gone through the link you provided. I am still not sure how to initialize 0.1% FAR and calculate the TAR%? It would be really great if you could explain?

Comment: Is there any way to make the question reproducible? in that way, more people can get involved and help you with, thanks @Iamnotperfect

Comment: Sure, I edited the post,  added the sample taken from @tripleee 's link

Comment: It would also be great if you give multiple examples. I really don't understand how to calculate this.

Comment: Can you still [edit] to show the values of `tar` and `far`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with ROC curve you know the curve itself does not give any specific value of `TRP (True Positive Rate)` and `FPR (False positive Rate)` for you model. It Simply track the evolution of `TPR` against `FPR` as you move some threshold over the distribution produced by the model.

So, if you want to calculate `TPR` at `FPR=0.1%` you have a couple of choices:

You either have the value `FPR = 0.1%` in `far` and you just have to retrieve its index to get the corresponding `TRP` or `tar` at the same position.

Or you do not have the exact value `FPR=0.1%` in `far` and in this case you can get the corresponding tuple `(far, tar)` below and above the value `0.1%` and perform linear interpolation to compute the exact value.

Comment: Interesting, So let us say we have 3 TPR  values at FPR = 0.1% (eg: TPR% = [89.99 , 90.01 , 90.02] at FAR% =[0.101, 0.102, 0.104,] ,  So how do I work on it? Should I average all of them?

Comment: @Iamnotperfect, At this point it's up to you, you could also take 0.101 as being the closest, or average the value around. There's no "good" or "bad" answer what's important IME is to understand what it means and why it make sense in your case.